# How to configure the mstsc span option in the RDP file

Tags: windows, rdp, mstsc

It is possible to fill the screen with an RDP session using the following command:
mstsc myconnection.rdp /span

Is there an option in the GUI settings dialog of the RDP file to have the span effect? I don't always want to type the command 7 run a batch script in order to fill the screen.

I would to configure it directly in the RDP file.

Comment: dont you want to use multimon instead ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx

Comment: No, I only want to occupy one monitor with the RDP session, but that one should be in fullscreen. But hey, I just found how to configure SPAN by adding it to the text of the RDP file in the link you provided. Thanks!

Comment: humm, if you set the display option to the largest value, you will have fullscreen : ![GUI option](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/117399)